# Why does this argparse code behave differently between Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, python-2.x

The following code, using argparse's subparsers, fails on Python 3 but runs as expected in Python 2. After comparing the docs, I still can't tell why.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def action(args):
    print(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    std = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    std.add_argument('standard')

    ap = ArgumentParser()
    sp = ap.add_subparsers()

    cmd = sp.add_parser('subcommand', parents=[std], description='Do subcommand')
    cmd.add_argument('arg')
    cmd.set_defaults(do=action)

    args = ap.parse_args()
    args.do(args)
```

The output from Python 2.7.6 is:

```
me@computer$ python test.py 
usage: test.py [-h] {subcommand} ...
test.py: error: too few arguments
```

In Python 3.3.5, I get:

```
me@computer$ python3 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    args.do(args)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'do'
```

Comment: Note that if you use a subparser: `args = cmd.parse_args()` it would work.

Comment: This code seems to give the same error for me on Python 2.7.4. Most likely you are running the wrong file version or something. It should not work. Try it more carefully again.

Comment: When I type your code in at a Python 2.7.6 interpreter, I get the same error at the line `args = ap.parse_args()`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

the latest `argparse` release changed how it tested for required arguments, and subparsers fell through the cracks.  They are no longer 'required'.  http://bugs.python.org/issue9253#msg186387

When you get `test.py: error: too few arguments`, it's objecting that you did not give it a 'subcommand' argument.  In 3.3.5 it makes it past that step, and returns `args`.

With this change, 3.3.5 should behave the same as earlier versions:

```
ap = ArgumentParser()
sp = ap.add_subparsers(dest='parser')  # dest needed for error message
sp.required = True   # force 'required' testing
```

Note - both `dest` and `required` need to be set.  `dest` is needed to give this argument a name in the error message.

---

This error:

```
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'do'
```

was produced because the `cmd` subparser did not run, and did not put its arguments (default or not) into the namespace.  You can see that effect by defining another subparser, and looking at the resulting `args`.

Comment: Thanks, that nailed it. In case there was any wonder, this solution is backward-compatible with Python 2.7

Comment: python 3.8.2.  I tried to set the required attribute, but got a traceback instead of a friendly help message.    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/argparse.py", line 2035, in _parse_known_args
    ', '.join(required_actions))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Comment: @tobixen, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/23349349/901925.  Did you set the `dest`?

Comment: No, didn't try dest (hm, it's written plainly in the answer above that dest is required, strange I didn't see it).  I tried setting required=True without success.  Ended up doing a workaround - https://github.com/tobixen/calendar-cli/commit/03f9e707eb1c74cc71ef30dad4b0fe3f70359fd0 - perhaps I'm doing this in the wrong way, but ... it works.