# Parsing argparse input bit by bit

Tags: python, parsing, parameter-passing, argparse

I am using [Argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) to parse shell input to my Python function.

The tricky  part is that this script first reads in a file that partially determines what kind of arguments are available to Argparse (it's a JSON file containing criteria by which the user can specify what data to output).

But before these arguments are added to my parser, I would like to read in some arguments relating to the file reading itself. (e.g. whether to fix the formatting of the input file). Kinda like this:

```
test.py (fix_formatting=True, **more arguments added later)
```

When I try to run `args = parser.parse_args()` twice, after the initial input and after adding more keys, things fall apart: Argparse quite predictably complains that some of the user input are `unrecognized arguments:`. I thought I might use [subparsers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) to that end.

So I tried variations of (following the example in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) as best as I could):

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')
    settingsparser = subparsers.add_parser('settings') #i want a subparser called 'settings'
    settingsparser.add_argument('--fix_formatting', action='store_true') #this subparser shall have a --fix_formatting
```

Then I try to parse only the "settings" part like so:

```
    settings=parser.parse_args(['settings'])
```

This seems to work. But then I add my other keys and things break:

```
    keys=['alpha','beta','gamma','delta']
    for key in keys:
        parser.add_argument("--"+key, type=str, help="X")
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

If I parse any input for any of the arguments from keys, Argparse complains that I make an `invalid choice: [...] (choose from 'settings')`. Now I don't understand why I have to choose from "settings"; the docs say that the parse

> will only contain attributes for the main parser and the subparser that was selected by the command line (and not any other subparsers)

- what is my error of understanding here?
- and if this is the wrong approach, how would one go about parsing one bit of input before another bit?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parse_args` calls `parse_known_args`.  This returns the `args` namesparse along with a list of strings (from `sys.argv`) that it could not process (`extras`).  `parse_args` raises this error if this list is not empty.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing

Thus `parse_known_args` is useful if you want to parse some of the input.

`sys.argv` remains unchanged.  Subsequent calls to a parser (whether it was the original one or not) use that again, unless you pass the `extras`.

I don't think subparsers help you here.  They aren't meant for delayed or two stage parsing.  I'd suggest playing with the documentation examples for subparsers first.

---

To the main parser, the subparsers look like

```
subparsers = parser.add_argument('cmd', choices=['select',...])
```

In other words, it adds a positional argument where the `choices` are the subparser names that you define.  That may help you see why it expects you to name `select`.  Positionals are normally required.

(there's an exception to this in recent versions, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22994500/901925)

Comment: thanks so much! i guess i totally mis-understood the concepts of subparsers as well as partial parsing. thanks for clarifying...